# Where to put data for your Android application

Tags: java, android, image, storage

Context: school assignment where I have to make a quiz for an Aphasia-diagnosis (in Java).

It's a quiz with 3 different types of questions and the type will be chosen in the first activity.
 One of the type of questions is "choose the X" with 4 different images portraying something different. 
Say I have 10 questions, that makes 40 images for that type of questions only.

As it is my second application in Android, I'm totally not familiar with the system (my main knowledge is WPF where u just had to throw it in some directory and then you could access everything you like) and I wonder where I have to put all my files (also textfiles with the questions, in a hierarchical file system)

Googling told me I should put all my images in res/drawable... but that seems absurd to me. Plus, as questions (and thus images) should be able to added later, I assume I need to have 1 file where everything is stored according to some taxonomy without having to change any code, right?

I've tried doing it by making an main/assets folder, and storing everything there, but I don't seem able to access those files via an .xml file.

I put in a screenshot of how my FS is organized.

[image: dir]

Comment: What is so absurd about drawable folder? You want to "draw" the image, right?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not supposed to put any .txt files there, right?
+ if someone would want to add any new questions later he'd have to know the hierarchy of the folder system (put images here, .txt-files there, audio files still somewhere else).
Shoot, should've mentioned there are also audio files possible, my bad

Comment: `assets` or `res/raw` are valid for text, audio, etc. You *can* place images there, but you wouldn't be able to use `R.drawable` or `@drawable`

Comment: Why can't android just load images from anywhere like WPF :'(
But if I, eg, sift through all the files and copy every .jpg to **res/drawable**, it makes connecting the right image to the right question nearly impossible unless i title all my images "typeXquestionYanswerZ.jpg", although that could be a last resort I guess...

Comment: It can load from anywhere. You are more than welcome to move your images to the SD card directly, just like an HDD that WPF would have access to. Assets are similar, but are private app storage. If you absolutely need the directory structure, then assets is the only option